# How to present ViewController in Landscape mode with rotation animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to present an `UIView` to landscape mode and make the device orientation changed to landscape at the same time, with a device rotation transform animation. How can I do that?

NOTE: My app is a portrait orientation only app.

Comment: What do you mean by rotation animation. Tell it briefly. @noinput

Comment: a 90/-90 transform.

Comment: So, in first view controller you want to present the second view controller and at the same time you want to rotate the view of second view controller by a 90/-90 transform in first view controller?

Comment: I've edited the description again. To put it simple, I want to present the UIView to landscape mode and change the device orientation to landscape at the same time, with a device rotation transform animation.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to design your second screen with auto layout enabling size class, and on viewWillAppear use following code

```
NSNumber *orientation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:orientation forKey:@"orientation"];`

You can subclass navigational controller for constraining landscape mode to single view controller.

Comment: While this may work, hard setting the value for API is never a safe route. What happens if Apple puts a different meaning of "orientation" in the next update? Your code would not work.